# scheme wrong-type-argument in attempted solution to Euler Project problem 7

Tags: scheme, lisp, primes

I've been trying to solve the [seventh Euler Project problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=7). My program looks like this:

```
(define (add-prime c)
    (define (smallest-divisor n) (find-divisor n 2))
    (define (find-divisor n test-divisor)
        (cond
            ((> (* test-divisor test-divisor) n) n)
            ((divides? test-divisor n) test-divisor)
            (else
                (find-divisor n (+ test-divisor 1)))))
    (define (divides? a b) (= (remainder b a) 0))
    (define (prime? n)
        (= n (smallest-divisor n)))
    (if (prime? (+ c 1))
        (+ c 1)
        (add-prime (+ c 1))))

(define (pv v c)
    (if (= c (vector-length v))
        v
        (begin
            (vector-set! v c
                (add-prime (vector-ref v (- c 1))))
            (pv v (+ c 1)))))

(let ((prime-vec (make-vector 10002)))
    (vector-set! prime-vec 0 2)
    (pv prime-vec 3)
    (display v))
```

The output looks like this:

```
In procedure add-prime:
In procedure +: Wrong type argument in position 1: #<unspecified>
```

I'm very confused. By itself, the `add-prime` procedure works correctly, it's just that when I combine it to create a vector containing 10,002 prime numbers, it returns this error.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use scheme for euler project.  Better to use numpy of pylab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your vector only at the address `0`

```
(let ((prime-vec (make-vector 10002)))
    (vector-set! prime-vec 0 2)
```

but then you go on filling it starting from the address `3`

```
    (pv prime-vec 3)
=
    (let ((v prime-vec) (c 3))
        ....
            (vector-set! v c
                (add-prime (vector-ref v (- c 1))))
        ....
=
        ....
            (vector-set! prime-vec 3
                (add-prime (vector-ref prime-vec 2)))
        ....
```

but you haven't initialized the contents of the vector at the address `2`, yet.

Racket uses the value `0` for the uninitialized addresses evidently, but your implementation apparently isn't and instead has `#<unspecified>` there, causing the error.

Start filling the vector from  address `1`, instead of `3`, and it should fix the error.

As a side note, `add-prime` is really `next-prime`. Naming is important, good naming can reduce the cognitive load.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in your code:

```
(let ((prime-vec (make-vector 10002)))
    (vector-set! prime-vec 0 2)
    (pv prime-vec 3)
    (display prime-vec)) ;; here you want to print the vector
```

If I run this program in `DrScheme`, it gives the following result, which seems kinda fantastic:

```
#(2 0 0 1 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 ...)
```